# My program can not properly access the date sets from MNIST

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

Good evening, I want to create a small neural network which is able to detect a number in an image. I'm using the datasets from [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

I've used [this code](https://github.com/HyTruongSon/Neural-Network-MNIST-CPP/blob/master/training_nn.cpp) and also [this code](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/99932) for testing, but something must be wrong with the decompression. The stored image and label values are always null. Below is my own code which doesnt work either.

```cpp
    extern const string mnist_img = "ressources/train-images.idx3-ubyte";
    extern const string mnist_lab = "ressources/train-labels.idx1-ubyte";

    void firstRead(){
    image.open(mnist_img,ios::in | ios::binary );
    label.open(mnist_lab,ios::in | ios::binary );

    char *number;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 16; ++i) {
        image.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(number), sizeof(4));
        cout << number << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
        label.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(number), sizeof(4));
        cout << number << endl;
        }
    }
```

The files are compromised with gunzip, I did use winrar to unzip them and the file sizes also match up with the decompromised files on the MNIST website.

Comment: Casting `number`, a `char *` , to `char *` seems an unusual decision, and in programming the unusual is often a bug. Perhaps `number` should not be a `char *`.

Comment: Thats definitely true, but the istream read() method takes a char pointer as the first parameter. Removing the cast doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: Apologies for being too oblique. Consider keeping the cast, but using a numeric type like `int`  for `number`. Any object can be read as an array of characters (note that the reverse is not necessarily true). If you define `number` as a 32 bit integer, `int32_t number;` and then `image.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(number), sizeof(number));` to read the data from the file into the integer you will probably get the behaviour you want. Currently the problem is `char *number;` doesn't point at any storage you can safely read into, and Crom only knows what will happen if you try.